# Is running multiple codes faster than running just one?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

my question is rather simple: if I have a code that has a for cycle that iterates 150 times. Is it faster to split this into 3 files where each for cycle iterates 50 times? If so do I run the 3 codes at the same time or one at a time?
Another option could be to use python `multiprocessing` in these 3 files, but the same question arises, do I run them all at once or one at a time?

Comment: Why not try out a few approaches yourself and use timeit https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html to see what's faster?

Comment: This depends strongly on what work is being done. Generally, yes, it'd be faster to run multiple processes, but that isn't universally true. Try both approaches and profile them to see what's best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - It depends.

In cpython, the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) ensures that only 1 thread in a given process can run python code at a time. If your loop is CPU bound, adding threads in a single process doesn't speed it up. If your loop sleeps for some reason like reading data from disk, threads can speed it up. Using multiprocessing, since the GIL is per-process, you may speed up processing.

There is overhead to multithreading and multiprocessing, including the cost of starting the thread / process, getting data to the thread / process and returning the result. Depending on what you are doing, this may be more expensive than the loop itself.

So, there is no general answer to this question. It is highly task dependent.

Comment: Is it possible to assign different cpu to different codes and run them at the same time. For instance, if I have two files and 4 cpu can I assign 2 cpu for each? I believe this could be possible, but I dont know if there is the possibility that 1 cpu ends up having to run two codes. So each code ends up using the same cpu

Comment: Normally you just run 2 processes and let the operating system figure out which core runs which. The operating system fully commits all cores so they would be running in parallel. You may find that the OS bounces the process among cores trying to find the best way to satisfy all processes that want to run. It is possible to pin a process to a core. This can have some benefit to increasing CPU cache hits but is highly program dependent. maybe reasonable for cache-optimized C code, but python not so much.